# Stacked polyline renderer for JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is there any renderer for JFreeChart for creating charts of stacked polylines?

I've tried using StakedXYAreaRenderer and StackedXYAreaRenderer2 with the idea of configuring it to display only the line and filling the area part with a transparent colour. After trying all the flavours of setXXXStroke and setXXXPaint on them I've been unable to display the line (setting the transparency has been easy).

Do I need to create my own renderer or is there any way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to be possible using [StackedXYAreaRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/StackedXYAreaRenderer.html) by specifying the type in the constructor:

```
StackedXYAreaRenderer renderer = new StackedXYAreaRenderer(XYAreaRenderer.LINES);
```

...but when I tried this in one of the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) demos I noticed a bug in the renderer that prevents it from working correctly.  This bug will be fixed (see [revision 2901](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2901/)) for the upcoming 1.0.16 release.

Comment: As the 1.0.15 has been released just now and looking at the periodicity of the project, I understand that the next one won't be realeased before 2015, am I wrong? Well, no problem, if I find a patch for the bug I will notify you. PS: Your project is awesome. My company asked for a report comparing your chart with IBM's ILog and yours was better.

Comment: The fix is already in SVN (the revision 2901 mentioned in my answer) and the JFreeChart 1.0.16 release should appear in Sept 2013.